# Emission factor of coal

Tags: thermodynamics

Emission factor of coal is 92.5 gCO2/MJ. What is physical significance of emission factor? How this value has been derived. Is it not 100 due to unburnt carbon

Comment: Why do you think it would be 100 gCO2/MJ? It’s not a percentage, and unburnt carbon is not emitted carbon.

Comment: You want to  produce 100MJ of electrical energy to feed into the grid. You could burn various fuels. How do you determine how much CO$_{2}$ you send up the stack as you make that 100MJ?